# Get the <div> outside of this <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get the second div (total-price), instead of the first div.

Additionally I would like to add a $ sign to the div, yet when it tries to convert the data into an Int, obviously "$" will cause an error.
I have a work around method for this, but is there anyway to concatenate the $?

Many thanks.

```
            <!-- Product #1 -->
            <div class="item">
                <div class="quantity">
                    <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button">
                    </button>   
                    <div class="total-price">22</div> <!--I dont want this one -->
                </div>
                <div class="total-price">22</div> <!--I want to access this div -->
            </div>
```

JQuery

```
                $('.plus-btn').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //Increase cost
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var $cost = $this.closest('div').find('div');
                    var costValue = parseInt($cost.html());

                    costValue += costValue;

                    $cost.html(costValue);
                });
```

Comment: `$this.parent().find('~ .total-price')`

Comment: I'd be more inclined to use [`.siblings('.total-price')`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: `.parent().find()` will look inside the parent.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.plus-btn').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var $this = $(this);
 var $cost = $this.closest('.quantity').siblings('.total-price');
 var costValue = parseInt($cost.html());

 costValue += costValue;

  $cost.html(costValue);
 });
```

Comment: can you elaborate on your solution on what it actually does and why it works?

Answer (score 1):

The `closest('div')` to the button is the div you don't want.

You can simply traverse one level up the DOM tree and to the parent `div` and find `'.total_price'` in its sibling.

```
$('.plus-btn').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var $this = $(this);
 var $cost = $this.parent().siblings('.total-price');
 var costValue = parseInt($cost.html());

 costValue += costValue;

  $cost.html(costValue);
 });
```

Comment: For the benefit of the OP and any future readers, can you please explain what you changed in the code and why? e.g. Why doesn't `$this.closest('div')` work?